# how to get chunks in diff3 algorithm implementation

Tags: diff3

I'm trying to implement diff3 algorithm and currently stuck at chunks creation stage. I already know how to get LCS between original file and "other" file and LCS between original file and "my" file. Which steps need to do to get chunks?

Comment: hi, sorry to reopen a old post, but im doing the same and am stuck at the same point. Did you get a solution?

Comment: Hello, unfortunately, no, I didn't get any solution...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this really answers your question, but Subversion implements this layering exactly as you describe here. It follows the theory quite closely, so you might be able to re-use some pieces.

See http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_diff/